# Ionic 2 modify Index.html

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I want to modify my index.html file when I build my app for development or production.

I need to inject one `<script>` if is production and other `<script>` if is development

Actually I use this  --->
https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-scripts

And this JS

```
const rollupConfig = require('@ionic/app-scripts/config/rollup.config');
const replace = require('rollup-plugin-replace');

const isProd = (process.env.IONIC_ENV === 'prod');
console.log('✓ ENVIRONMENT IS PRODUCTION: ', isProd);

const rollupConfigReplaceEnviroment = replace({
  exclude: 'node_modules/**',
  // use the /environments/environment.dev as the default import(!), no stub needed.
  // note we only replace the "last" part of the import statement so relative paths are maintained
  '/environments/environment.dev' : ( isProd ? '/environments/environment.prod' : '/environments/environment.dev'),
});

rollupConfig.plugins = rollupConfig.plugins || [];
rollupConfig.plugins.splice(0, 0, rollupConfigReplaceEnviroment);

module.exports = rollupConfig;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to call build differently to use that rollup config:
`"build": "ionic-app-scripts build --rollup ./config/rollup.config.js",`